# System.NullReferenceException Context.Item.Axes.SelectSingleItem

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I recently added the Sitecore WebAPI nuget package and have been getting null reference errors when hitting any controller method that makes a reference to my base settings item. My base settings item is defined as follows:

```
public static class ItemReferences
{
        private const string _configurationItemQueryByName = ".//ancestor::*[@@templateid='{{SOME_ID}}']/../Settings";
        public static Item GetConfigurationItem()
        {
            return Context.Item.Axes.SelectSingleItem(_configurationItemQueryByName);
        }
}
```

I'm guessing it has to do with this being in a static context but I don't want to take it out of a static context because it doesn't change and many pieces of the website use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an exception because `Context.Item` is always null on your controller.
Try to change it so it uses `Context.Database.GetItem()` to get your configuration item.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. Good call.